# Wrapping a PipedInputStream with a BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, groovy, stream, io, pipe

I have an OutputStream that I needed to read from, and so I used the following (Groovy) code to get an InputStream reference to the data:

```
PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream()
    PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream)
    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Some API method
                    putDataInOutputStream(outputStream)
                    outputStream.close()
                }
            }
    ).start()

handler.process(inputStream)
```

In this case, handler is some class that implements an interface which has this method:

```
public void process(InputStream stream);
```

The problem that came up in our new requirements was that there was some pre-processing on the stream, and therefore I need to read the stream at least twice in the handler.process() method.  Here's some example code from one implementation:

```
public void process(InputStream stream) {
    def bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(stream, 30 * 1048576)  // 30 MB
    bufferedStream.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    parseMetadata(bufferedStream)
    bufferedStream.reset()
    doTheThingYouDo(bufferedStream)
 }
```

I know that for some input I am **not** hitting the 30 MB limit or the **Integer.MAX_VALUE** buffer size.  However, I'm always getting the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Is this even possible?  I think the problem is the thread closing on the PipedOutputStream, but I don't know how to prevent that or if perhaps I'm creating more problems by being a novice at Java Stream IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that your `parseMetadata` somehow closed the stream. I've tried your scenario, and it works fine for me. In general, closing the `OutputStream` before your handler is done reading is not the problem, that's exactly what the piped streams are for.

Besides, given your situation, I would leave out the piping, and the additional thread. If you don't mind having your entire stream in memory, you can do something like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

fillTheOutput(out);

ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

pass1(in);
in.reset();
pass2(in);
```

If you do mind having everything in memory, you're in trouble anyway, since your `BufferedInputStream` does roughly the same thing.

**edit**: Note that you can easily build a new `ByteArrayInputStream` based on the byte array, which is something you cannot do with regular streams.

Comment: Yes, good point about the buffered input stream.  Either way it looks like the heap could be huge.  The size of these buffers/byte arrays could be several hundred MB and there could be many processing at the same time.  Right now the other option on the table is a work file for reading it in twice, but perhaps getting the byte array once and using it as necessary could be better.